# Extra padding in select option element in chrome

Tags: css, select, padding

I have a select element where I enable users to choose the classification and description. In chrome browser only, I have an extra padding which I am not able remove with padding:0 or with other css tags. [Screen from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3iIb.png)

However, the same element in other browsers does not have any padding. See example screen from firefox.[Screen from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoyXd.png)

Any idea why this can be the case?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Images are nice but we prefer code.

Comment: Issue is only verifiable under specific circumstances (see answer below).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE #2**
Based on my own experience, and those of users on the google forums, this only seems to affect users on Windows 8 and Windows 10 displays with **touch-sensitive** screens.
(Please ignore my previous update re: Windows 10 and font-scaling!)

See here: [Chrome Support Forum - Dropdown Option Height](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IO4USajnHOQ;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/select$20option$20padding)

The appearance css does nothing to fix it (note that if you put the appearance styles on the select element, then the drop-arrow disappears)

Here's some sample code - happens only on my touch-sensitive laptop, and only in  Chrome. All of my other machines render correctly. IE and firefox render correctly in all machines.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        html, page, body 
        { 
            padding:0; border:0; margin:0;
            font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        select {
            padding: 0px 8px;
        }
        option {
            -webkit-appearance:none;
            -moz-appearance:none;
            appearance:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding:20px;background-color:#887b93">
        <select name="vendorId" id="vendorId">
            <option value="">--- Select Vendor ---</option>
            <option value="86">Alexandra</option>
            <option value="5">Alix</option>
            <option value="73">Anna</option>
            <option value="19">Anne</option>
            <option value="60">Avant</option>
            <option value="65">Blue</option>
            <option value="84">Blush</option>
            <option value="21">Carol</option>
            <option value="89">Christos</option>
            <option value="43">Claire</option>
            <option value="25">Cynthia</option>
            <option value="54">Dauphines</option>
            <option value="22">Delphine</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the bug only affects Win10 or the fix only affects Win10?  Windows 8.1 also suffers from the forced additional padding.

Comment: Confirm that this occurs in Windows 10, but only for touchscreen machines. Also, confirmed that no CSS seems to affect (fix) the issue.

Comment: Just started happening on my desktop as well - Windows 10 1809, non-touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

This may help reset all the browser-specific styling for select elements:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
```

Comment: No effect on this issue.